# Arduino USB read/verify

Tags: c++, arduino

I am very new to the arduino platform and am looking to reach out to those with far more experience to help me. Let me try to explain what I am trying to accomplish the best that I can:

I want to get a USB female type A onto a arduino board, and allow for it to verify information from a USB drive as part of my project. Once the USB is inserted, If there is a code or a piece of data present on the USB; The arduino will confirm that validity of the information, and send a request to a door lock to allow it to unlock. Is this possible?

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to integrate a USB-A female jack with your Arduino, plug in a USB drive, check that drive for some data, and perform an action if that data is present?

Comment: Yes this is in essence exactly what I want to have happen. this could be elementary, but as im new to arduino im just hoping for some guidance

Comment: This seems a job for a more "intelligent" device, like a Raspberry PI or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right I think you need a USB Host.

If I'm not misstaken this is only available on Arduino Due

See[Arduino Reference USBHost](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/USBHost)

Comment: So the Arduino Due doesnt come with a USB built in. I could just add one w/ the available connectors & it would work the way I am requesting? That would be excellent! thank you

Comment: Please check the interfaces that are supported by the USBHost class referenced in my link. I think only keyboard and mouse is supported. I don't know if this is right for your use case.

Comment: If you plan to read a file or a directory from a USB stick or a USB disk I would rather use a Raspery PI for e.g.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case you need to set Arduino in USB Host mode. Select an Arduino device which can be configured as usb host mode. Then you can read the content of the attached USB drive(which is in USB device mode)

See this link to get an idea about [USB Host vs Device mode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49140/what-exactly-are-the-difference-between-a-usb-host-and-device)

See this link for USB [Host shield for Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoUSBHostShield). This will support [USB Mass storage Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class) which is required to read data from USB Mass storage class drives